# Property does not exist on type '{ my_function(): void; }'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am a newbie in both TypeScript and VueJS. Currently, I am thinking about the most appropriate way of setting the type for a json key that should initially be null.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    export default Vue.extend({
        data: {
            return {
               value: null
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

This way, when I set this.value = 123, TS throws an error saying it can't assign number to null. Well, not surprising. My question is, what is the most elegant way to handle this case. One approach is to define an interface like this:

interface INullableString {
value: number | null;
}

```
<script lang="ts">
        import Vue from 'vue';
    
        export default Vue.extend({
            data(): INullableString {
                return {
                   value: null
                }
            },
        });
</script>
```

Is there more DRY or cleaner way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` keyword to set the type of a variable to something more or less specific than what typescript infers automatically.  In this case, you would declare the type `as null | number` meaning that it can be either `null` or a `number`.  We initially set it to `null`, but now we are able to change it to a `number` without issue.

```
{
  value: null as null | number
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzRLW)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean `INullableNumber`.

Why not just use:

```
ReturnInterface { 
    value?: number; 
}
```

Though that will then be `number | undefined`. Does it have to be null?

Also I wouldn't call your interface `INullableNumber` as it's not just a nullable number. It's the return object of the `data()` function. So you probably want to give it a more declarative name. I'm not sure of surrounding code but an example could be `IReturnData`.